# remove a substring from filename

Tags: string, command, line, dos

i got at work a folder with several audio files like that:

trad58.french.mp3
trad49.french.mp3

housework84.english.mp3
housework86.english.mp3

i would like to remove the language name and i don't know how to do it under windows 7.
both have the same pattern so i will create 2 different batch files to customize them, but basically if i'm taking the tradxx.french.mp3 files, i tried:

> FOR %%F IN (trad*) DO CALL :process GOTO :eof
>
> :process  set fname=%%F
>       ren "%fname%" "%fname:french=%"
>
> :eof pause exit /B 0

but it does not work.

Any idea ?
thx.

Comment: I won't post an answer, in case you are more interested in the programming aspects. But if all you want is to get those files renamed) which would have been better asked on SuperUser), you can't beat   http://www.antp.be/software/renamer

Answer (score 0):

You could list all the files with a same pattern
*english.mp3

And you could trim strings with DOS commands, check this example

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
set oldname=ABCDEFG.english.mp3
echo.  %oldname%

set newname=!oldname:~0,-12!
echo.  %newname%.mp3
```

Then check this guide: [DOS substring manipulation](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php#Snippets.TrimRightFOR)

All you need to do is put inside your for loop a "move" or "ren" command with the new file name computed from the original name .